# Pandas CSV reader: read time increases with skiprows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata

I am working with a big dataset of sequential data, length of which might differ.

Currently using `pd.read_csv(series_file, skiprows=..., nrows=...)` and it works on small datasets, but goes nuts when **skiprows** argument gets bigger.

Are there any ways to work with big data and keep track of previous csv search session? Using **chunksize** seems to be a good solution, but it doesn't work with different size data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your chunk size is greater than max seq len. Since that you are required to use paddings, you need to calculate it anyway.
2. Keep the last seq group and append it to the first in the next batch or just merge with the batch

my final solution was:

```
class PreSeqDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, max_seq_len, ch_size, series_file):
    self.max_seq_len = max_seq_len
    self.series_file = series_file
    self.ch_size = ch_size

def process_series_batch(self, series):
    ...
    return series


def __iter__(self):

    last_batch = None

    for chunk in pd.read_csv(self.series_file, chunksize=self.ch_size):

        series_batch = None

        ids = chunk['object_id'].unique()


        if last_batch is not None:
            if last_batch[0] in ids:
                chunk = chunk.append(last_batch[1])
            else:
                ids = list(ids)
                ids.insert(0, last_batch[0])
                series_batch = self.process_series_batch(last_batch[1])

        for i in ids[:-1]:
            series = chunk.loc[chunk[chunk.columns[0]] == i]
            series = self.process_series_batch(series)
            if series_batch is None:
                series_batch = series
            else:
                series_batch = torch.cat((series_batch, series))
        last_batch = (ids[-1], chunk.loc[chunk[chunk.columns[0]] == ids[-1]])
        series_batch = series_batch.to(device)
        yield ids[:-1], series_batch
```

Answer (score 0):

using Python 3.7 I see no issue. I tried to skip 100,000 lines

```
import pandas as pd
path = r'C:\Temp\tmp.csv'
trg = open(path, 'w')
trg.write('col1,col2\n')
for i in range(10**6):
    trg.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(i, i*2))
trg.close()
df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=10**5, nrows=30)
```

Comment: when there are 453,653,104 lines it quickly becomes a problem