# Pandas read-time increases with skip rows value increase

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

I am working on reading a medium sized text file (175132 rows) that contains rows of varying column numbers, separated by space. I need to read different parts of the file and transform into an array for further processing.

I found a similar thread from the past, but it didn't help me much.
[Pandas CSV reader: read time increases with skiprows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024565/pandas-csv-reader-read-time-increases-with-skiprows)

Snippet of file I am reading

```
  56567.       57232.       58031.       58989.       60138.    
   61518.       63173.       65160.       67544.       70404.    
   73837.       77956.       82899.       88831.       95949.    
 XX resistivity
  2.51187E-03
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    

     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000    
     0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000       0.0000
```

I have the following function that reads the required line and transforms it to the array I need.

```
def read_table_block_to_row(file, skip, nvals, ncols):
    Row_values=np.zeros((1,nvals))
    for row in range(int(np.ceil(nvals/ncols))):
        st = time.time()
        skiprows=skip+row
        row_arr=pd.read_csv(file,sep='\s+', skiprows=skiprows, nrows=1, header=None).to_numpy()
        for col in range(ncols):
            idx=row*ncols+col
            Row_values[0,idx]=row_arr[0,col]
    return (Row_values)
```

I notice that the runtime increases significantly as the value of skip in my function increases. I therefore tested the times taken on the line that is reading the *row_arr* and this seems to increase with the value of *skiprows*.

After doing some timing tests on code blocks, I think the issue is with the line

```
row_arr=pd.read_csv(file,sep='\s+', skiprows=skiprows, nrows=1, header=None).to_numpy()
```

Values from time tests:

- skiprows = 941 , time = ~0.0057s
- skiprows = 37421 , time = ~0.021s
- skiprows = 73901 , time = ~0.038s
- skiprows = 110381 , time = ~0.048s

Please note that this time increase is for reading a single row from the file. This translates to a significant increase in time as I try and read different code blocks.

It is taking about 30-45 min to read the file, which I think is a bit too long.

Any suggestions on reading of blocks quicker would save a lot of time. Maybe there is a  solution outside of pandas?

SOLUTION: (Sharing if it helps someone in future)
One of my initial issue/confusion was that I was unable to read the entire data frame directly using pandas due to varying column width.

Luckily, if I skipped the first 2 lines of the text file, I had sufficient column width to read the entire data directly.

Then I defined a function to flatten the dataframe as per my requirement.

```
# After the first 2 rows, we have the max no. of cloumns in the file, so we can read from there.
data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=2, header=None, sep='\s+')

Then read and transform the data to the format I want using this function.
def read_row(df,start,end):
    row_data = data.iloc[start:end,:].unstack().to_frame().dropna().droplevel(level=1).reset_index(drop=True).T
    return row_data
```

It cut down my run time for reading the file from about 45 min - 1 hr to 11s.

Comment: Use python CSV module instead. If you are on a Unix machine, then read using cat or some other Unix tool before passing to  pandas

Comment: @sammywemmy Is there a way to skip multiple lines in CSV module? I might be able to try the unix solution, but prefer python only solution if it is possible

Comment: yea, so you write it using generators. If you can share the sample data (as a csv file), I can script sth and send back to you. Kindly share the output form as well

Comment: How do you share csv/text file? I am sorry, its the first time I have posted on stack overflow, so it isn't obvious to me from the options I can find here.

Comment: Put it on Google drive or some other hosting service and share the link

Comment: @sammywemmy I found the solution by reading the entire dataset into a data frame and then doing my data manipulation (transforming into l x n x m arrays) from the data frame. This reduced the runtime from ~1 hour to 11 s. It just highlights my inefficient thought process of trying to read one line of text file at a time.   I will edit the post with my solution if it ever helps someone else. I will also share a google file as I would like to know if there is an even more efficient way of reading the file, which might become useful if the file is even bigger.